# How to get UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL from UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL ?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any way to get the MediaURL from ReferenceURL ? I want to upload the image to S3 server which needed the filePath for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just mention it as off topic here: `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` is deprecated now, first deprecated in iOS 11.0. So it's better to just use `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`.

Answer (score 0):

From `MediaURL` you can get the `ReferenceURL`, you need to save that 'UIImage`in your`DocumentDirectory` and then you can get that path and upload it to S3.

```
let imageName = "temp.png"
let documentDirectory = try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
let imgPathUrl: NSURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)    
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)
data!.writeToFile(imgPathUrl!.path!, atomically: true)
print("Path \(imgPathUrl!.path!)")
```

Now you can upload from that path!

Comment: I want MediaURL from ReferenceURL, anyways thanks :)

Comment: You can't! @coreDeviOS